# Custom parameter does not send the parameter of button clicked in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

So i'm learning google tag manager and I was playing around with setting up a way to check which of my "Give us a try" buttons is clicked by passing a custom parameter to GTM. However, no matter what button I click it sends the same value of "Hero Trial" and not the value of the actual button clicked.

My first test button is

id="Trial-Button" with a custom parameter of ganame="Hero Trial"

and second test button is

id="Trial-Button" with a custom parameter of ganame="Navigation Trial"

I set up the trigger to work on Click all elements and trigger on "Click ID" that matches Trial-Button"

A variable that is "Dom Element" and selection method "Click ID" and send the ganame parameter as a variable

Then a tag that sets the ganame parameters as an event parameter.

Any ideas on what might be going on? I'm very new to this so please let me know what information you need from me to make this possible if I have not provided it.

Answer (score 0):

GTM has no special knowledge of custom attributes you add to tags - you'd generally have to write code specifically to capture the value of this attribute via custom JavaScript.

First you're going to need to set up a variable so you can pull the resulting value out of the data layer. Create a new user-defined variable of type "Data Layer Variable". Give it the variable name you'll push to (I use 'ganame' in my own code example below) and give the variable itself a name. I use 'GaName' here.

[image: GA Variable]

Create a second variable that we'll use as a trigger to fire off our final GA tag. In the script below, we'll be pushing a value to the data layer called 'myEvent', so we set it accordingly and call that trigger 'Button Click Event'.

[image: Button Click Event Variable]

Add a DOM ready trigger (and limit by page as needed) since you don't want to execute this script until the document object model has loaded (the thing all the HTML represents) as elements may not be loaded prior to that.

[image: DOM Ready Trigger]

Add a custom event trigger using the 'Button Click Event' variable we set earlier. This should trigger when it has a value of 'gaButtonClick' as you'll see in the script below. We'll call this trigger 'GA Button Click'.

[image: GA Button Click Trigger]

You can't really use the built-in event handlers in GTM because of that need to pull the custom attribute off the element, so we'll instead create a custom HTML tag that fires on this DOM Ready trigger. We'll use the following script in it - see comments for explanations of what's happening. Note that the custom script tag expects HTML to be written to it, thus the `<script>` tags in the image.

#### Edited code to remove arrow functions

```js
//Find the button on the page and add an event listener for when someone clicks it
  document.querySelector('#Trial-Button').addEventListener("click", function(){
    //Get a reference to the button again within the click event handler and pull the custom attribute off
    var attr = document.querySelector('#Trial-Button').attributes['ganame'] || '=';
    //Since this returns 'ganame=myValue', we split and pull the second value
    var attrVal = attr.split('=')[1];
    //Push this into the data layer
    dataLayer.push({'myEvent': 'gaButtonClick', 'name': attrVal});    
});
```

[image: Button Capture HTML Tag]

Finally, you'll presumably want to send this captured value somewhere. Let's say you're sending it to Google Analytics 4 as a custom event. Create a GA4 Event tag. Set this up with whatever event name you want to use in your reporting, then populate the event parameters. I specify a name of 'name' below, and reference the GTM variable we created earlier with the use of `{{GaName}}`. Trigger this tag with our 'GA Button Click' event we created earlier.

[image: GA4 Tag]

To review what happens here:

1. The user visits the page and the DOM is loaded
2. The `ganame Button Capture` tag is executed, finds your button by ID and attaches a click event handler to it.
3. When the button is clicked, it pushes two values to the GTM datalayer: a myEvent value and a name value. Both variables are saved to GTM variables.
4. Since the myEvent value matches its associated trigger value, this fires the GA4 event tag which populates the value of the event parameter named 'name' with the value of the variable 'GaName'.

Done!

Comment: Hi Whit, thank you so much for your comprehensive explanation. However, i'm very new to all this and I keep getting this error when trying to publish (specificly it's giving me this error on the ganame button capture HTML tag

-----Error at line 3, character 69: This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT_2015 mode or better: arrow function.-----

any ideas? Thank you. Id love to test if this works for me. appreciate it^^

Comment: @BrettWilliams I didn't change the screenshot, but I've updated the code snippet to remove the use of the arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem and tried to apply the method described in the other answer. And I believe that I found a more elegant solution.

GTM does distinguish custom data attributes. And you would not have to write custom JS to capture them. As described in the [bounteous blog post](https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2017/07/07/track-more-click-detail-data-attributes-and-google-tag-manager):

> Each attribute you set up on the page should have its own data layer
> variable in GTM. The key is in its name. Each Custom Data Attribute
> has two parts as we mentioned above, the first being “data-” and the
> second being something unique like “make” or “published“.

That implies, however, that you need to adjust the parameter in your example and use "data-ganame" instead.

Using "data-" in the custom attributes is a general best practice, which allows GTM to automatically read that information.

So, all you will need to do is to create a Data Layer Variable with the value "gtm.element.dataset.ganame".

[gtm.element.dataset.ganame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sas2.png)

Then create a Tag with an All Elements trigger Click ID = Trial_Button, and a custom parameter (e.g. "button_name") that returns the Data Layer Variable {{dlv-ganame}} of a button that user clicks.

[example tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWqoF.png)